# Using useState reacthook in a reactjs module is throwing error: Invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, rollup

I am trying to create a reactjs module, develope and maintain separately from the main reactjs app I am working on.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function MyComponent(props) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, React!</h1>
      <p>This is a basic React component.</p>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

The build configurations look pretty much like this: https://github.com/iamsmkr/react-module-starter and the module is being used as per [README](https://github.com/iamsmkr/react-module-starter/blob/main/README.md).

Usage in the `App.js`:

```js
import MyComponent from 'react-module-starter';

function App() {
  return (
    <MyComponent></MyComponent>
  );
}

export default App;
```

App `package.json` looks like (Note that the app was generated by `create-react-app`):

```json
{
  "name": "test-react-seesaw",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Trying to use `useState` hook is throwing error:

```bash
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at resolveDispatcher (react.development.js:1476:1)
    at useState (react.development.js:1507:1)
    at l (index.js:4:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17811:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19049:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964:1)
```

I'm not sure if there is anything wrong with my build configuration or something? This is the first time I am trying to develop reactjs module and utilize in apps. Please suggest.

Comment: It looks like the version mismatch would be the place to start - making sure the starter code you're using matches up with the version of react you have installed

Comment: I would guess that `App` is rendered incorrectly

Comment: @jmcgriz I have updated the question with the `package.json` used in the App. I already thought of this issue and tried matching the `react` and `react-dom` version of both the app and the lib but still facing the issue. Do you find anything incorrect with the `package.json`?

Comment: @Konrad Could you please elaborate on this? What is wrong with the rendering?

Comment: Does `useState` work if you use it in the `App` comoponent?